# iPad button doesn't get custom CSS

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

I've given to buttons a custom css. It works great on:

- Windows Desktop (Chrome, Opera, Edge)
- Windows Desktop through console mobile device demo
- Android (Opera, Chrome)
- iOS (Safari, Chrome)

The problem is that on iPad it doesn't work.

The css is this:

```
input[type="button"],
    button,
    .theater-control-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none; /*Safari/Chrome*/
        -moz-appearance: none; /*Firefox*/
        -ms-appearance: none; /*IE*/
        -o-appearance: none; /*Opera*/

        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    }
```

On iPad it looks height: 15px and with border radius: 30px.

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing your

```
<button type="button">
```

to

```
<button type="submit">
```

in your HTML

and, of course, in your CSS

```
input[type="submit"],
    button,
    .theater-control-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none; /*Safari/Chrome*/
        -moz-appearance: none; /*Firefox*/
        -ms-appearance: none; /*IE*/
        -o-appearance: none; /*Opera*/

        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    }
```

This solved once same issue for me on iPad, hope it helps.